# HC 05 / Arduino connection issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, arduino, android-bluetooth

I am getting the following exception while sending the data from `Xamarin.Android` app to `Arduino` through Bluetooth  module `HC-05`

```
read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

I have read all the answers that are already there but none of them solved it.

I have used the following code.

```
_adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
            if (_adapter == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!_adapter.IsEnabled)
            {
                const int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
                var enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ActionRequestEnable);
            }

            var pairedDevices = _adapter.BondedDevices.ToList();


            if (pairedDevices.Any())
            {
                foreach (BluetoothDevice dev in _adapter.BondedDevices)
                {
                    bonded.Add(dev);
                }

                 bluetoothDevice = _adapter.GetRemoteDevice(bonded[0].Address);


                _adapter.CancelDiscovery();

                btSocket = bluetoothDevice.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Java.Util.UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

                btSocket.Connect();

                btSocket.OutputStream.WriteByte(messageBytes[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sockets issue

You can use my  [`Bluetooth class`](https://github.com/harounhajem/DroidBarBotMaster/blob/master/DroidBarBotMaster/DroidBarBotMaster.Android/Class/Service/BluetoothService.cs) i used in Xamarin, Android app, when i connected to my `HC-05`, read after **line 208** in the code.

Also in my github repo you can find the Arduino, `HC-5` code under [ArduBotSlave](https://github.com/harounhajem/ArduBarBotSlave). It's a cocktail mixing machine, the Arduino part, which takes orders from an Android app, the Xamarin part.

### Permissions issue

Do you have all the required permissions for using Bluetooth? Some permissions fail silently and show up as an bug.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```